# Remove Escape Characters From Hangfire Result

Tags: c#, hangfire

Whenever I return an object as a result of a Hangfire job the object is serialized into JSON but always contains escape characters making the output look quite hard to read.

I have also tried returning a string after serializing myself but its the same. This makes me think its most likely related to the display element rather than the serialization itself.

For example if I return the following object from a job

```
 var person = new Person
            {
                Name = "john",
                Description = "male",
                Role = "manager"
            };
```

The output will look like this on the dashboard for the job instance.

```
Result: "{\"Name\":\"john\",\"Description\":\"male\",\"Role\":\"manager\"}"
```

Is there anyway to tell hangfire to not display escape characters in the result field. It would be nice to have new lines when viewing json output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around in the codebase for Hangfire I discovered this isn't something that can be configured. The renderers for the elements on the job details page output html encoded with the escape characters.

As a work around though I used this library that extends Hangfire with an output console so I can output custom information here instead of the result field.
https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console